# Replacing ASP.NET Identity Login & Register Pages with Modal, but receiving InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I am trying to replace the default login and register pages that come with ASP.Identity to bootstrap modals instead. The way I am trying to do this is by rendering two partial views in the `_LoginPartial` view. The partial views contain the modals and the corresponding ids for the `data-target` html attributes. Here is the `_LoginPartial` view:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</a>
</li>

<!-- Login Modal -->
<div id="login-modal-container">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_LoginModalPartial");
    }
</div>

<!-- Sign up Modal -->
<div id="register-modal-container">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_RegisterModalPartial");
    }
</div>
```

The partial views that I am rendering are using different view models i.e., `@model LoginViewModel` & `@model RegisterViewModel`. The problem is that whenever I load  a page that uses its own  model, I receive this error: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'OSM.Models.RegisterViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OSM.Models.LoginViewModel'`. I am confused, can someone explain why this is occurring in basic terms and any possible alternatives. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MvC, we can't pass multiple models from a controller to the single view. There is a few ways we can get around this which are explained in the following article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/